# Erlang - ALIVE2_REQ from non local address

Tags: rabbitmq

I am testing my Erlang environment and it is not working. I am using debian 64 bit. Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

In one terminal I type the following command to start elang in debug mode

```
pkill epmd
epmd -d
```

In another terminal I type

```
erl -sname test
```

I get the following error

```
epmd: Wed Feb 25 13:00:28 2015: ** got ALIVE2_REQ
epmd: Wed Feb 25 13:00:28 2015: ALIVE2_REQ from non local address
```

This has prevented me from running rabbitmq server

Comment: This is related to this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/erlang/+bug/1374109. Seems like it is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was with my iptables. The POSTROUTING chain specifically. Checking iptables list

```
iptables -t nat --list
```

showed

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir out pol none
```

so I removed the MASQUERADE  rule

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
```

after that checking the iptables list showed

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and this made erlang to work.