# rabbitmq server node is not starting

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm not able to start rabbitmq node.
the logs are here

```
Dec 30 05:21:56 staging systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ Messaging Server...
Dec 30 05:21:56 staging epmd[21037]: epmd: ALIVE2_REQ from non local address
Dec 30 05:21:56 staging epmd[21037]: epmd: ALIVE2_REQ from non local address
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging epmd[21037]: epmd: ALIVE2_REQ from non local address
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging rabbitmq[20954]: Waiting for rabbit@staging ...
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging rabbitmq[20954]: pid is 20971 ...
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging rabbitmq[20954]: Error: process_not_running
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ Messaging Server.
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 30 05:21:57 staging systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
```

and epmd logs

```
epmd: Sat Dec 30 05:24:22 2017: epmd running - daemon = 0
```

and status is:

```
failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-12-30 05:21:57 UTC; 23min ago
```

Comment: This is not nearly enough information. Please provide RabbitMQ version, Erlang version, operating system and version, as well as the complete set of logs from `/var/log/rabbitmq`. You should archive the logs and share them somehow, not paste them here. As an alternative, provide all of that information in a message on the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) mailing list. The RabbitMQ team monitors that list (myself included).

Comment: It solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/28761582/4591943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen mostly because POSTROUTING rules in iptables. List them as:

```
iptables -t nat -v -L POSTROUTING -n --line-number
```

We can find lots of `MASQUERADE` entries here if we can remove all `MASQUERADE` rules from the list it will work.

remove rules using

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING {number-here}
```

After this restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server
```

Now it works healthy.

```
worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
(filter-PrlgTpdp) aircto@staging:~/apps/filter$ systemctl status rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-11 12:40:20 UTC; 4h 52min ago
  Process: 11759 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11758 (rabbitmq-server)
    Tasks: 69
   Memory: 44.6M
      CPU: 1min 49.068s
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─11758 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
           ├─11774 /bin/sh -e /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
           ├─11909 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-7.3/bin/beam -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -K true -B i -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitm
           ├─12009 inet_gethost 4
           └─12010 inet_gethost 4

Jun 11 12:40:17 staging systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ Messaging Server...
Jun 11 12:40:18 staging rabbitmq[11759]: Waiting for rabbit@staging ...
Jun 11 12:40:18 staging rabbitmq[11759]: pid is 11774 ...
Jun 11 12:40:20 staging systemd[1]: Started RabbitMQ Messaging Server.
```

Comment: You are GURU! Huge thanks! Please add to your answer: correct iptables rule is : `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype ! --src-type local -j MASQUERADE`